# Next JS 13.3 'use client 'gives unexpected error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

Next JS 13.3.0 has a bug or another way to use "use client"?
I have tried of several ways and always have the error:

wait  - compiling...
event - compiled client and server successfully in 909 ms (562 modules)
error - SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse ()
wait  - compiling /favicon.ico/route (client and server)...
event - compiled successfully in 95 ms (310 modules)

I tried to use "use client" in my component and in its father components. It's the same.

I expected the it works find, it's just a useState as always.

I have found that downgrading to a previous version it can be fixed, but it is not the idea.

Comment: Can you share your code and what page/route the error is occuring in?